# nodejs how to execute other js file from index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create web app with nodejs but with structure like this

```
- modules
  | - module1
      | - module1.js
  | - module2
      | - module2.js
- index.js
- settings.js
```

- First, i never use nodejs from scratch
- Second, i know you will suggest using any other framework, sorry guys here i want to understand how nodejs and may be other nodejs framework works.
- Third, this is for educational purpose

---

in `modules/module1/module1.js` :

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')
res.end('Hello World aw!')
```

honestly i dont know how to code it properly, what i really want is i wanna execute that code and response to browser `Hello World aw!` from index.js :

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  //in here i call modules/module1/module1.js, and execute the code
})
```

and how to do that properly? so it can run well

Comment: in module1.js you create function(req, res) and export it and in index.js you require that module and put `router.get('/', theFunction);`

Comment: see https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Docs is the first thing to look into more about tech. And secondly try to do a bit of R&D to learn more in depth for educational purpose .

Answer (score 0):

to load any script or module in `nodejs` you need to use `require`

like this

```
var module1 = require(__dirname + 'modules/module1/module1.js');
```

and then you can use `module1` anywhere in your code

BTW for express you should create routes and then attach that routes to your app. See example below.

`users.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

`server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var users = require('./routes/users');
....
app.use('/users', users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time with node when you need to have a module in a particular page you need to require this module.

example: you want to get the library [express](http://expressjs.com/) so at the top of your file who you want this library you do something like that.

```
var express = require('express');
```

Now you can use express in all the file. When this is a node library you just need to require the name.

this is the same thing with a file you create and you want inside a other one

```
var myfile = require('./../myfile');
```

with that you can use the word myfile inside all the file. But you need to figure out the path to this one.

A good links for read about [this](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)